# Вывести данные из массива в таблицу

Tags: javascript, html

у меня есть

```
<ul contenteditable="true" id="ul" value="gg">
<li>chr2 123456789 321456789 gain</li>
<li>chr5 891234567 987654321 gain</li>
<li>chr3 123456789 123498765 loss</li>
</ul>
```

потом я получаю эту информацию и делаю массив

```
 var fields = document.getElementById('ul').innerhtml;

 var arr = fields.split(' ');
```

как подскажите нарисовать таблицу 
пробовал как то так но ничего не получается

```
var html='<table><tr>';
for (var i=0;i<arr.length;i++){
html+='<td>'+arr[i]+'</td>';
}
html+='</tr></table>';
```

Comment: А что не выходит-то?

Comment: вывести массив в таблицу

Answer (score 3, accepted):

С помощью матрицы легко сделать:

```js
document.querySelector('#result').innerHTML = `<table border='1'>${Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('#ul li')).map(e => e.innerHTML.split(' ')).map(e => `<tr>${e.map(e => `<td>${e}</td>`).join``}</tr>`).join``}</table>`;
```

```html
<ul contenteditable="true" id="ul" value="gg">
<li>chr2 123456789 321456789 gain</li>
<li>chr5 891234567 987654321 gain</li>
<li>chr3 123456789 123498765 loss</li>
</ul>
<hr />
<div id='result'></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Еще вот такой вариант:

```js
var 
  fields = document.getElementById('ul'),
  items = fields.getElementsByTagName('li'),
  body = document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0],
  tbl = document.createElement('table');

for(var i = 0; i < items.length; i++){
  
  var  item = items[i].innerHTML;
  
  var tr = document.createElement('tr');  
  
  var arr = item.split(' ');
  
  
  for (var j = 0; j < arr.length; j++){
    var td = document.createElement('td');
    td.innerHTML = arr[j];
    tr.appendChild(td);
  }
  tbl.appendChild(tr);
}

body.appendChild(tbl);


//fields.remove();
```

```html
<ul contenteditable="true" id="ul" value="gg">
  <li>chr2 123456789 321456789 gain</li>
  <li>chr5 891234567 987654321 gain</li>
  <li>chr3 123456789 123498765 loss</li>
</ul>
```